# In my absence in/over..? How to specify the period correctly

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

I would like to know whether the following is correct or should be improved:

> John will stand in for me in my absence over the next week and half.

I am especially unsure about the preposition (over).

Answer (score 1):

The part "over the next week and a half" is fine. But I'd change the "in my absence". to "during my absence".

```
John will stand in for me during my absence over the next week and half.
```

Because "in my absence" could mean it's not a certainty that you are absent. But considering you are specifying a time period, it does not play together that well in my opinion.

e.g:

```
 In my absence, you should contact John.
```

Which would mean that in case you are absent, John is the "go-to" person. It does not mean that you *will be* absent.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is good as written. In this case, you are using over to mean during. There's nothing wrong with it.